# php curl fetching links of a url

Tags: php, curl, url-rewriting

I have a fetched a URL. If we fetch a URL in that page when we click on the links these are to be fetched by curl.  How can I do it?

Comment: not understanding your question.

Comment: what do you need to do ?

Comment: can you give us some code and example of what you wish to accomplish?

Comment: i want to fetch all links of a url through curl...

Comment: a crwaler that will fetch  Processors information from http://www.amd.com/uk/products/desktop/processors/Pages/desktop-processors.aspx.
From the above ink i want to find the procesor name and description for the rest of information like 'Features', 'Product Info', 'Comparison' and 'Support' info i will have to go to the product page.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are talking about crawling. You got a page and want to crawl the links that are inside of this page.

- http://www.google.com/search?q=php+crawler